# Ionic/Android bypass validation

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have a simple login form with a username/email field and a password field. Everything works fine if the username field type is text but I set it to email instead to include the @ on the keyboard and now if it is not a valid email address the scope variable is undefined. I have tried using novalidate="true" but it's still the same problem.